# How to retrieve list of model objects from firebase databse

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

**Model Class**

```
    public String id;
    public String total;
    public List<CartModel> orderList;
    public String currentDate;
    public String orderBy;
```

I want to fetch these objects but unfortunately can't do this.
I'm accessing this list in my adapter class like the following way but getting null value.

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrderHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Orders model) {

        List<CartModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = model.getOrderList();
        Log.i("Orders", list+"");

        holder.dateTime.setText(model.getCurrentDate());
        holder.grandTotal.setText("Total "+model.getTotal());
        holder.orderBy.setText(model.getOrderBy());

    }
```

**Please provide me a valid solution for doing this**

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your field in the Java code doesn't match the property name in the JSON.

To make them match, change:

```
public List<CartModel> orderList;
```

To:

```
public List<CartModel> orderItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String userid="your unique id";
String orderid="your unique id";
DatabaseReference database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
databse.child("yourroot")
       .child("Users")
       .child(userid)
       .child("Orders")
       .child(orderid)
       .child("orderItems")
       .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener {
            @Override 
            void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                //handle error as per your requirement
            }

            @Override 
            void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                YourModel model=snapshot.getValue(YourModel.class)
                //use the model or add to adapter payload and notify it on mainthread
            }
        })
```

Note: you may get `DatabaseException` if your model class is not an appropriate class to hold values from the DB.